# How can I return when a middleware goes next()?

Tags: node.js, express

I use `express-ip-access-control` in order to do ACL checking.

My middleware function goes like this:

```
const ipAccessControl = require('express-ip-access-control')

function accessControl (req, res, next) {
    ipAccessControl(someOptions)(req, res, next)

    // additional ACL checking logic
    ...
    switch(result) {
        case ALLOW:
            next()
            break
        case DENY:
            res.status(400).send("denied")
    }
}
```

That ipAccessControl does work well, but I don't know how to return when ipAccessControl allows access and calls next().

The above code always does both ipAccessControl and additional ACL checking logic.

Is there a way to check the result of ipAccessControl, and return only when ipAccessControl calls `next()`?

I don't want my additional checking logic to be called when the access is allowed by ipAccessControl.

That ipAccessControl should be called before the additional ACL checking logic.

Any thought appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your own function in place of `next()` and then you will know when it is done:

```
const ipAccessControl = require('express-ip-access-control')

function accessControl (req, res, next) {
    ipAccessControl(someOptions)(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            // call the actual next with the error
            return next(err);
        } else {
            // additional ACL checking logic
            ...
            switch(result) {
                case ALLOW: ...
                case DENY: ...
            }
            // when done successfully, call next() here
            // or if there's an error, then send an error response
            // or call next(err)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain more? I don't want my additional checking logic to be called when the access is allowed by `ipAccessControl`. When `ipAccessControl` doesn't validate the access, I re-check with my additional code.

Comment: @yoon - You need to explain better what `ipAccessControl()` does and when exactly you do and don't want to execute more code as perhaps my first interpretation of what you were trying to accomplish is not complete.  Please explain more.  When I look at that module's documentation, it looks like it sends an error status response when it does not authorize and calls `next()` when it allows.  So, exactly what case do you want to execute more code for?

Comment: My program checks IP ACL and hmac authorization. A request is rejected only when neither of them meets. I use ipAccessControl for IP ACL. If a request meets this ACL condition, it allows the afterward operations. If a request is from an unknown IP, rather than rejecting the request, it checks again whether the request is hmac authorized. If it's hmac authorized, program accepts the request.

Comment: @yoon - As best I can tell the `ipAccessControl()` module is not written to be used that way.  It is middleware that calls `next()` when it succeeds or sends an error response when it doesn't.  Other than some giant hack that tries to monkey patch the request to intercept and prevent it from sending a response, I don't see any way to know it has failed the check and let you continue with your other code.

Comment: @yoon - If this was my code, I would probably fork the `ipAccessControl()` module and change it so it could be used as a regular function that returns a result that let me use normal logic with it so it never sends a response.  Or, replace it without something else that lets my logic work the way I want.